# using assert in combination with imported simpleType with enumerations

Tags: java, xml, xsd

i'm building a service to verify application forms using xsd, those application forms will use common types, so i want to be able to re-use them.

But i also want to use xsd 1.1 assertions, to verify a combination of fields.

I am unable to move my common types to a seperate xsd and also use assertion, assertion will only work with a type that is in the same xsd.

These were the initial xsd, xml and code i created, with the common type "CoverType" still inside the ApplicationForm schema and the xsd as a local file:

Applicationform.xsd:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:xerces="http://xerces.apache.org"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning">
    <xs:element name="policy" vc:minVersion="1.1">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="surname" minOccurs="1" />
                <xs:element name="coverType" type="CoverType" minOccurs="1" />
                <xs:element name="annuityPercentage" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:assert test="(coverType = 'LEVEL' or coverType = 'LINEAIR') or (annuityPercentage > 0) "/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:simpleType name="CoverType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="LEVEL"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="ANNUITY"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="LINEAIR"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

This was the corresponding test.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<policy>
    <surname>test</surname>
    <coverType>ANNUITY</coverType>
    <annuityPercentage>0</annuityPercentage>
</policy>
```

I'm using Java and Xerces J 2.11 to load the ApplicationForm.xsd, this is a code snippet:

```
public class ValidationHandler {
    static final String xsdLocationtest = "C:/dev/workspace/xsd/ApplicationForm.xsd";
    static final String language = "http://www.w3.org/XML/XMLSchema/v1.1";
    public File xsdtest;

    public boolean validate(StreamSource xmlSource) {   
        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(language);
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(xsdtest));
        Validator newValidator = schema.newValidator();

        try {
            validator.validate(xmlSource);
        } catch (IOException | SAXException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage());
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

`newValidator.validate()` triggers the assertion rule.

This assertion rule will result in an exception if the rule is not met, throwing "cvc-assertion.3.13.4.1: Assertion evaluation .... did not succeed", where ... is the assertion rule from the xsd.

The above works as intended, setting annuityPercentage  to 0 would result in an assertion error, anything above 0 would not.

But i am unable to move common types to a second xsd, in combination with assertions, because now the assertion rule is always triggered, also with correct input.

If i remove the assertion, the validation works, but only validates basic rules like minOccurs.

In the code below, CoverType is moved to a seperate xsd file, CommonTypes.xsd.
I also changed the type name from CoverType to CovertypeType.

This is the content of CommonTypes.xsd, now holding CovertypeType:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="https://mywebsite.com/xsd/CommonTypes"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            elementFormDefault="qualified" >
    <xsd:simpleType name="CovertypeType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="LEVEL"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="ANNUITY"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="LINEAIR"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

This is the new content for ApplicationForm.xsd:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:cmn="https://mywebsite.com/xsd/CommonTypes"
            xmlns:xerces="http://xerces.apache.org"
            xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="https://mywebsite.com/xsd/ApplicationForm"
            elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="CommonTypes.xsd"
                namespace="https://mywebsite.com/xsd/CommonTypes" />
    <xsd:element name="policy" vc:minVersion="1.1">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="surname" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" />
                <xsd:element name="coverType" type="cmn:CovertypeType" minOccurs="1" />
                <xsd:element name="annuityPercentage" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:assert test="(coverType = 'LEVEL' or coverType = 'LINEAIR') or (annuityPercentage > 0) "/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

I changed the test xml to match the new ApplicationForm.xsd:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<afo:policy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="https://mywebsite.com/xsd/ApplicationForm ApplicationForm.xsd"
        xmlns:afo="https://mywebsite.com/xsd/ApplicationForm" 
        xmlns:cmn="https://mywebsite.com/xsd/CommonTypes" >
    <afo:surname>test</afo:surname>
    <afo:coverType>ANNUITY</afo:coverType>
    <afo:annuityPercentage>1</afo:annuityPercentage>
</afo:policy>
```

I also updated the Java code to use the xsd from a URL instead of a file:

```
public class ValidationHandler {
    static final String language = "http://www.w3.org/XML/XMLSchema/v1.1";

    public boolean validate(StreamSource xmlSource) {   
        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(language);
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new URL("https://mywebsite.com/xsd/ApplicationFormOrv.xsd"));
        Validator newValidator = schema.newValidator();

        try {
            validator.validate(xmlSource);
        } catch (IOException | SAXException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage());
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Any hints/help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know whether Xerxes cares, but your namespace URIs ("CommonTypes" and "ApplicationForm") are not, in fact, URIs.  At least a scheme is required.  For example, you might use "urn:x-MyApplication-CommonTypes", etc..

Comment: In fact, if Xerxes is interpreting those as relative URIs (which it shouldn't, but then again, it shouldn't accept them at all), then the important question is *relative to what?*  My first guess would be relative to the URIs of the documents in which they appear, in which case "CommonTypes" means different things in your different schema files.

Comment: @JohnBollinger i updated my question, based on your comments and more research, the assert rule still doesn't work though, i'm wondering if Xerces is to blame. it's hard to find a good xsd validator that handles xsd 1.1.

Comment: I have a philosophical appreciation for Xerces, but I'm more inclined to trust Saxon.  Have you tried that?